# subsets [that are of length l] of list in S size

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, powerset

hi i already looked throw the forum but didn't found solution to my problem.
the problem is :
how can i find all the possible subsets [that are of length l] of list in S size .
and return it in a list.

Comment: Look for the powerset recipe in [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

Comment: [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: ^^ The python documentation is the first place you should go.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18155089/2545927 might do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate all possible permutations of subsets containing all the element of a set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154860/generate-all-possible-permutations-of-subsets-containing-all-the-element-of-a-se)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [162]: x=[1,2,3]
     ...: from itertools import combinations
     ...: print [subset for i in range(len(x)+1) for subset in combinations(x, i)]

#outputs: [(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

to do that **without combinations**:

```
In [237]: import numpy as np
     ...: x=np.array([1,2,3])
     ...: n=2**len(x)
     ...: res=[]
     ...: for i in range(0, n):
     ...:     mask='{0:b}'.format(i).zfill(len(x))
     ...:     mask=np.array([int(idx) for idx in mask], bool)
     ...:     res.append(x[mask].tolist())
     ...: print res
#output: [[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: thank you ! but there is another way for doing it without combinations?